# In Apache Thrift How Should Date Objects Be Represented

Tags: datetime, thrift, cross-language

In the Thrift IDL there isn't a Date type.  What's the best cross language mechanism to represent a date object.  I think there are 2 ideal candidates but I'd love to hear other ideas.

1. String - in each language you could use something like strftime to convert the date back.
2. i32 - Time since epoch can be converted back.

I'm sure there are other things to think about besides conversion.  Hoping people out there have some good feedback.

Comment: Use i64 to represent data objects.

Answer (score 11):

**tldr;** use an appropriate-encoded string unless there is a reason to do otherwise.

It depends on what is required. Here are some differences - keep in mind that *modern computers are fast* and conversion is likely only a small fraction of overall application time so "more processing" is generally not even be applicably measurable!

String (with [**ISO 8601**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) or the stricter [XML dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime)):

- "more space" / "more processing" (*see above*) / fixed size or variable size
- standardized culture-neutal format
- human readable and *easily identifiable*
- supports timezones
- more range (-9999 to 9999)
- more/arbitrary precision (up to 1us)
- lexicographically ordered (within same timezone and compatible format)

Epoch (UNIX variant):

- "less space" / "less processing" / fixed size
- standardized culture-neutral format
- *not* human readable (a diligent coder should be able to identify "about now")
- *no* timezones (can't even distinguish between "local" and UTC)
- *less* range (1970 to 2034 with a signed 32-bit number)
- *less*/fixed precision (1 second)
- numerically ordered

(The [Julian day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) is another encoding with many similarities to an Epoch time.)

Conclusion:

Unless space/performance *is* a proven issue - this requires a performance analysis and functional requirements - I'd pick the former. Computers today are a good bit faster than computers just a few years ago and *much, much* faster than computers decades old.

Comment: like this answer. human readable date time representation saves lots of debug time.

Comment: This is likely to never get read, but "no timezones" is one of the *benefits* of a UNIX timestamp. All times are always represented in UTC. Simple, easy, effective, no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Just for posterity, you may be interested in temporenc (http://temporenc.org), a comprehensive binary encoding format for dates and times.